# RegEx for LINQ like syntax

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a string in the format:

```
MyList.Where(abc).GroupBy(def).Sum(ghi)
```

The Where & GroupBy parts are optional as is the argument to the function, so.

```
ThisList.Count
```

is also valid.

I'm trying to find a RegEx string that will match this and return the values:
The List name (e.g. MyList), the where condition (e.g. abc), the GroupBy attribute (e.g def), the function name (e.g. Sum) and the function attribute (e.g. ghi).

**Clarification:**
The List name is one word
abc can be a complex expression, but there will be no close brackets which are not in quotation marks
def will be a single word
ghi will be a single word or a list of words separated by ","

Comment: How complex will the abc, def, and ghi parts be? You say "LINQ like", but is this actually C# code? For instance, is this possible? `MyList.Where(p => p.Value > MyOtherList.Where(i => i.Age < 40).Count)`

Comment: Nope, there where will be a list of boolean clauses with && between them
e.g. MyList.Where(arg1 = 'Hello' && arg2 = 23)
I'm not ruling out that a close bracket might somehow sneak in in a string though, e.g. MyList.Where(arg1 = 'D(O)H')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<list>\w+)\s*
([.]\s*Where\s*[(]\s*(?<wherearg>.*?)\s*[)]\s*)?
([.]\s*GroupBy\s*[(]\s*(?<groupbyarg>.*?)\s*[)]\s*)?
[.]\s*(?<func>\w+)\s*[(]\s*(?<funcarg>.*?)\s*[)]
```

Comment: Nice! How would I make the brackets for the function argument optional?
e.g.
List.Count should work as well as List.Count()

Comment: Change last row like this: `[.]\s*(?<func>\w+)\s*([(]\s*(?<funcarg>.*?)\s*[)])?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to validate the syntax, like:

```
^[A-Za-z]+(\.[A-Za-z]+\([A-Za-z]+\))*(\.[A-Za-z]+)?
```

but this will result in a *valid* or *invalid* decision.

I am not sure if you really want to grep the method names and values at the same time. That would limit your syntax: for instance all methods (GroupBy, Where) have to be in the right order. Maybe it is easier to split the string by `.` and extract the parts you need one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming where/groupby/function parameters to be words, you can use:

```
^(\w+)(?:\.Where\((\w+)\))?(?:\.GroupBy\((\w+)\))?\.(\w+)(?:\((\w+)\))?$
```

- Group 1 would have the list name
- Group 2 would have the where condition or null
- Group 3 would have the group by condition or null
- Group 4 would have the function
- Group 5 would have the function parameter or null

If they're going to be complex C# expressions, the corresponding regex will be quite complex that you'll hate yourself tomorrow for choosing regex for this.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the expected result.

```
^(?<List>[^\.]\*)|\.(?<Op>[^\(\.]*)\(*(?<Param>[^\)\.]*)
```