# RegEx / Parsing Linq - List.Where(xyz).Sum(value)

Tags: c#, linq, parsing

I have a linq like syntax:
**MyListName**.***Where***(Lots of stuff can() "be" in "Diff(" here).**Sum**(value)

I am wondering whether to use a RegEx or my own parsing function?

I need to return:
List = MyListName  and
WhereCondition = Lots of stuff can() "be" in "Diff(" here
Function = Sum
FunctionParameter = value

e.g. the where brackets must match otherwise syntax error. The where condition is optional, the function is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx for LINQ like syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093095/regex-for-linq-like-syntax)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Wouldn't CodeDom be a better approach? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/codedomcalculator08082005003253am/codedomcalculator.aspx

Comment: What I am doing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439637/using-expression-evaluator-to-execute-dynamic-linq-strings-on-multiple-enumerable

Comment: Similar to RegEx for LINQ like syntax post, but the answer to that didn't handle multiple brackets within the Where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies, I do not have enough reputation to comment. But the [answer to RegEx for LINQ like syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093095/regex-for-linq-like-syntax/3093282#3093282) **WORKS** for multiple brackets within the Where clause.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Also, You should have enough reputation now.