# Using expression evaluator to execute dynamic LINQ strings on multiple Enumerables - DLR / NCalc / Flee?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic-data

I have a generic object with properties:

```
Class MyObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Object> properties = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    public object this[string name] { get { return properties[name]: null; }
}
List<MyObject> People= new List<MyObject>();
People.Add(new MyObject(age = 50, home = "Dublin", name = "Bob", Income = "50"));
People.Add(new MyObject(age = 45, home = "London", name = "Tim", Income = "90"));

List<MyObject> Cities= new List<MyObject>();
Cities.Add(new MyObject(City = "Dublin", Country = "IE"));
Cities.Add(new MyObject(City = "London", Country = "UK"));
```

I would like to be able to query these Enumerables by using Linq, but these queries are **dynamic** and would be in strings, e.g.

```
People.
Where(a["age"] > 45 && Cities.Where(b["Country"] == "IE").Contains(a["home"]).
Sum(c["Income"])
```

Any recommendations? I'm currently using [Ncalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com) with lots of switch statements that call Linq code...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)